# How to draw a square of 1cm in LaTeX filled with color?

Tags: color, boxes

How to draw a square of 1cm in LaTeX filled with colour? I found `mdframed` and `framebox` does this, but there need to write text inside it. I just need to draw a box.

Comment: `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble, and `\tikz{\path[draw=red,fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1cm);}` where you need the rectangle.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the simple `\rule` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}

\crule{1cm}{1cm} \crule[blue]{1cm}{1cm} \crule[red!50!white!100]{1cm}{1cm}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gotta love `\rule`.  Very versatile considering its original purpose.

Comment: I think overprinting two colored rules would be general enough for draw/fill distinction :)

Comment: How to make this into several lines? maybe in n x m grid? tabular and newline doesn't work :-(

Comment: use a `tabularx` and define the left rule with `!{\vrule width 1cm}`

Comment: How to make a vertical line with the boxes so that no space between the boxes?

Answer (score 16):

No-one has a box that is drawn and filled yet*, which is possibly what was meant in the original question.  And for what it's worth, here is a completely different way of getting a 10mm box - use fbox around a null box.  8-)

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
\fboxsep=4mm \fboxrule=1mm
\fcolorbox{black}{blue!40!white}{\null}
```

[image]

Edit: * my apologies, there are solutions above with drawn/filled boxes.  No pictures of such though.

Comment: How can I fix the box? The starting letter is downward the box.

Comment: How to align the box with the text ?

Comment: from memory, `\fcolorbox` aligns with the baseline of the internal box, which in this case is a 0x0 box.  You can create a larger internal box with a `\phantom` so that it gets an appropriate baseline.  Maybe something like `\fboxsep=2mm \fboxrule=1mm \fcolorbox{black}{blue!40!white}{\phantom{\vrule width 4mm height 4mm}}`.  Or just use `\raisebox`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `tikz` and `\newcommand` to have a small command for box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycbox}[1]{\tikz{\path[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1cm);}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \mycbox{blue}
    \mycbox{red}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering why you load pgfplots and set the option `compact=1.7` while just loading tikz would be sufficient for your purpose... `:)`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Yes, my fault. I just take a scratch TeX file with `pgfplots`, instead of `tikz`.

Comment: I supposed that `:)`

Comment: Overkill, I think, when compared with `\rule`

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Although perhaps a bit overkill, I would always recommend Tikz over `\rule`. To me its easier to understand and it gives better, more controllable results.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: My solution is less overkill.

Comment: @Mythio: why is a solution with tikz "more controllable"?

Comment: @Herbert: because it has a lot more options for styling, etc as far as I'm aware. Although I admit my experience with `\rule` is limited, so it might have options too.

Answer (score 8):

With PSTricks. Compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape main`.

[image]

```
% the filename is main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Side,\Side)
 \psframe*[linecolor=\Color](\Side,\Side)
 %\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=\Color,linestyle=none,dimen=middle](\Side,\Side)
 %\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=\Color,linestyle=none,linewidth=0](\Side,\Side)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}



\def\Square[#1,#2]{%
\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{latex "\def\Side{#1}\def\Color{#2}\input{dummy}"}}%
\immediate\write18{dvips dummy}%
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf dummy.ps dummy-#2.pdf}%
\includegraphics{dummy-#2}%
}

\begin{document}
This is a red square \Square[12pt,red] and this is a blue one \Square[15pt,blue].
\end{document}
```

### Edit 1:

Based on HV's comment below: The code above apparently can be simplified as follows. Again, compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape main`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}

\def\Square[#1,#2]{%
\begin{postscript}
\psframe*[linecolor=#2](#1,#1)
\end{postscript}}

\begin{document}
This is a red square \Square[12pt,red] and this is a blue one \Square[15pt,blue].
\end{document}
```

### Edit 2:

The code in edit 1 does not produce a tight output for the squares. Therefore, we have to explicitly pass `--hires` to `pdfcrop` as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[pdfcrop={--hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\def\Square[#1,#2]{%
\begin{postscript}
\psframe*[linecolor=#2](#1,#1)
\end{postscript}}

\begin{document}
This is a red square \Square[12pt,red] and this is a blue one \Square[15pt,blue].
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\def\Square[#1,#2]{\begin{postscript}\psframe*[linecolor=#2](#1,#1)\end{postscript}}` will do the same!

Comment: @Herbert Exactly what do you want the document to look like, and how should it be compiled?

Comment: @SvendMortensen: It also needs the  `-shell-escape`option with `pdflatex`. That's all, together with the `\begin{document} ...`

Comment: @Herbert The following will not compile: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\Square[#1,#2]{
  \begin{postscript}
  \psframe*[linecolor=#2](#1,#1)
  \end{postscri‌​pt}
}

\begin{document}

This is a red square \Square[12pt,red] and this is a blue one \Square[15pt,blue].

\end{document}`

Comment: @SvendMortensen: my files: http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/square.tex and http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/square.pdf

Answer (score 7):

All solutions above expand to

```
\hbox{\pdfliteral{0 0 1 rg}\vrule height1cm width1cm depth0cm\pdfliteral{0 g}}
```

at pdfTeX level. The only difference (when TikZ is used) is that you need to read 26560 lines of code from 56 external files. What does TikZ? It implements programming language for picture programming using programming language for typesetting. Sometimes seems to be more functional to use the original language for typesetting directly. I mean that this is this case.

Comment: While I agree that calling TikZ for the sole purpose of drawing a square is overkill, I firmly disagree with this false simplicity: the `\rule` solution ***doesn't*** expand to those low level commands when XeTeX is used or a route such as `latex+dvipdfmx` or `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`.

Comment: If a person often uses TikZ then the cognitive resource cost of avoiding it may well be much greater than the cpu's resource cost of using it.