# Symbol at the end of partial answer

Tags: math-mode

How can achieve the following:

[image]

I would like to be able to insert a symbol at the end of partial answers. In the above image all three squares are added by me. (They do not perfectly align.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
v = v_0 + a \Delta t\\
\Delta s = \frac{1}{2}(v_0 + v_1)t
\end{eqnarray}

Substituting (1) in (2) gives:

\[\Delta s = v_0 + \frac{1}{2}a (\Delta t)^2\]

Eliminating $v_0$ gives:

\[\Delta s = v_1 - \frac{1}{2}a (\Delta t)^2\]

Finally, eliminating $t$ from (1) and (2) gives:

\[v_{1}^{2} - v_{0}^{2} = 2a\Delta s\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Example of code?

Comment: @egreg Is this MWE suitable?

Comment: Now I'm not sure why you'd want those squares.

Comment: @egreg I am trying to find a way to emphasize both the final answer and the partial answers. So the lines with an empty square at the end are supposed to denote a partial answer, and the black square is supposed to denote the final answer.

Comment: I can see no advantage. The final black square should be the “end of proof”. The open squares serve no purpose, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align}
....\tag*{$\square$}\\
...\notag\\
....\tag*{$\square$}
\end{align}
```

Comment: `\square` is available from `amssymb` package, not the `amsmath` package I believe. Please also put more effort into your answers (all of them, actually...). At the very least, complete the code in your answer with `\documentclass{...}` etc..

Answer (score 0):

To draw a square refer to this answer: [How to draw a square of 1cm in LaTeX filled with color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106984/how-to-draw-a-square-of-1cm-in-latex-filled-with-color)

To align it with the last line add the square as a tag to that line i.e. `\tag{\tikz{\path[draw=red,fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1cm);}}` if you are using the align environment