# Custom TOC Title style

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, pagestyle

I'm desperately trying to make this TOC Title style, the problem is that I don't know how to make that black box near the TOC title. I'd be able to make the same style in the picture but with title (and bbox ofc) aligned to the right. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code an image can you pleae it give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what you are doing, what packages you are using, what your document class is and this makes it almopst impossible to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.I is really difficult to help you without more information.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works! It's based in what you can read here: [How to draw a square of 1cm in LaTeX filled with color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106984/how-to-draw-a-square-of-1cm-in-latex-filled-with-color)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\crule{1.6cm}{.7cm} Contents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{First section}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]