# How to draw three squares of 1cm with variable space between filled with color?

Tags: color, draw

Today I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106985/194545) solution in LaTeX Stack Exchange how to draw three squares of 1cm filled with color but I don't found a way to change the space between the squares. I want to get them closer.

Comment: How much closer?

Comment: it's exactly the same as three letters, there there is a word space  it is `a b c`  If you want no space use `abc`  or for custom space `a\hspace{1mm}b\hspace{1mm}c`

Comment: @Mico I thought about 0.1 cm between the squares

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That did it for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a font size of 10pt, 1mm of horizontal whitespace is not that different from just the basic interword space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%% simplified the '\crule' macro for the sake of this example
\newcommand\crule[1][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}
\begin{document}

\crule{} \crule[blue] \crule[red!50!white!100] 

\crule\space\crule[blue]\space\crule[red!50!white!100]

\crule\hspace{1mm}\crule[blue]\hspace{1mm}\crule[red!50!white!100]

\crule\hspace{0.5mm}\crule[blue]\hspace{0.5mm}\crule[red!50!white!100]

\crule\crule[blue]\crule[red!50!white!100]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly the same as three letters, there there is a word space it is `a b c`

If you want no space use `abc` or for custom space `a\hspace{1mm}b\hspace{1mm}c`